# How can I use piechart chart in react native

Tags: react-native, pie-chart

I am using React Native 0.66 yet I want to integrate it piechart, dognut chart charts, I used this package  `"react-native-pie-chart": "^2.0.2",`
I am running on Simulator `ios 14` 
**Actual output**
`Required Native component ArtShape was not found in the UIManager`
** Expected output**
PieChart
**Source codes**

```
import PieChart from 'react-native-pie-chart';
export default class DashoardChart extends Component {
   const widthAndHeight = 250;
   const series = [123, 321, 123, 789, 537];
   const sliceColor = ['#F44336', '#2196F3', '#FFEB3B', '#4CAF50', '#FF9800'];
   
render() {
    const widthAndHeight = 250;
    const series = [123, 321, 123, 789, 537];
    const sliceColor = ['#F44336', '#2196F3', '#FFEB3B', '#4CAF50', '#FF9800'];

    return (
      <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Basic</Text>
          <PieChart
            widthAndHeight={widthAndHeight}
            series={series}
            sliceColor={sliceColor}
          />
          <Text style={styles.title}>Doughnut</Text>
          <PieChart
            widthAndHeight={widthAndHeight}
            series={series}
            sliceColor={sliceColor}
            doughnut={true}
            coverRadius={0.45}
            coverFill={'#FFF'}
          />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So many packages crack the app but I have found package called `"react-native-pie-chart": "^2.0.2",` which shows `shows doghnut chart` I tested it on `ios` app